# itextsharp and TLS 1.2

Tags: ssl, itext

We have recently upgraded our web servers from TLS 1.0 to TLS 1.2 and I am now getting an error message (Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel) when creating a new PDFReader:

iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader pr = new PdfReader();

I added this line before calling the PdfReader create

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

But still receive the error. Is itextsharp not compatible with TLS 1.2?

Comment: What version of iTextSharp and .Net are you using? iTextSharp calls into the .Net runtime for almost IO stuff so there shouldn't really be any specific version dependencies that I can think of.

Comment: What are the PdfReader parameters? As said earlier by Chris itextsharp uses the standard .NET IO to comunicate, the usual test is to load the data to a byte array and see what happens.

Comment: Check the client certificate and the client certificate chain. Does it contain any certificates that are expired or that uses hash algorithms that aren't deemed secure enough for TLS 1.2?